# Prove that: $\sin \,\cot^{-1} \cos \,\tan^{-1}x = \sqrt{\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2+2}} $.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Prove that: $\sin \,\cot^{-1} \cos \,\tan^{-1}x = \sqrt{\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2+2}} $.

This question was taken from Miscellaneous Example of S.L. Loney's *Trigonometry*.

Since, the question involves 2 parts, LHS and RHS, LHS is completely Trigonometric while, RHS is algebraic, so my approach was to get taylor series for $x+1$ then differentiate it and keep on doing to show that both sides are same... But, I wonder if there is an trigonometric solution for the question too or not!

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

When you compose trig functions with inverse trig you get algebraic functions.  I always draw a right triangle.  If we first assume the angle is in the first quadrant, we have 
[image]
where $\tan^{-1}x$ is angle $A$ and $\cos A=\frac 1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.  Now draw a new triangle for the next two functions.  Then you need to make sure it works for other quadrants because of the ranges of the inverse trig functions.

Answer (score 3):

Let $y=\tan^{-1}x$. Then $\tan y=x$ and so drawing a right triangle with angle $y$ and sides $1,x,\sqrt{1+x^2}$, we find $\cos y=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

Now let $t=\cot^{-1}(\cos y)$. Then $\cot t=\cos y=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$, so drawing a right triangle with angle $t$, we find the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{2+x^2}$, so $\sin t=\sqrt{\dfrac{1+x^2}{2+x^2}}$.